Problem Passing HTTP Request Data to jPOS Filters
I'm working on a Spring-based application that uses jPOS to handle ISO8583 messages. I want is to allow scripts (in JavaScript or Python) to modify these ISO messages. To achieve this, I have set up a mechanism to execute scripts that can alter the ISO messages.
However, I am facing an issue when trying to pass data received from an HTTP request (via a Spring controller) to the jPOS filter, as the filter is invoked by jPOS itself.
mport jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.jpos.core.Configurable;
import org.jpos.core.Configuration;
import org.jpos.core.ConfigurationException;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOChannel;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOException;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOFilter;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg;
import org.jpos.util.LogEvent;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@Slf4j
public class MessageModifyFilter implements ISOFilter, Configurable {
    private String requestScriptPath;
    private String responseScriptPath;

    private String loadScript(String path) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
    }

    @Override
    public ISOMsg filter(ISOChannel channel, ISOMsg m, LogEvent logEvent) throws ISOFilter.VetoException {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

            String scriptPath = isRequest(m) ? requestScriptPath : responseScriptPath;
            String script = loadScript(scriptPath);

            String functionName = isRequest(m) ? "modifyRequest" : "modifyResponse";
            log.info("Applying " + functionName + " script");
            return (ISOMsg) ScriptExecutor.executeScript(script, functionName, m, scriptPath, request.getAttribute("EXPOSED_PARAMS"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("Possibly failed to execute script or the execution returned null!");
            log.warn("Therefore returning original object without modification");
            return m;
        } catch (ISOException e) {
            log.info("There was error processing the ISOFilter", e);
            log.warn("Therefore returning original object without modification");
            return m;
        }
    }

    private boolean isRequest(ISOMsg m) throws ISOException {
        return m.getDirection() == ISOMsg.OUTGOING;
    }

    @Override
    public void setConfiguration(Configuration cfg) throws ConfigurationException {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(cfg.get("request-modifier-script-Path"))) {
            this.requestScriptPath = cfg.get("request-modifier-script-Path");
        }
        if (StringUtils.hasText(cfg.get("response-modifier-script-Path"))) {
            this.responseScriptPath = cfg.get("response-modifier-script-Path");
        }
        if (requestScriptPath == null) {
            log.warn("---REQUEST MODIFIER SCRIPT FILE NOT PROVIDED---");
        }
        if (responseScriptPath == null) {
            log.warn("---RESPONSE MODIFIER SCRIPT FILE NOT PROVIDED---");
        }
    }
}


import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Context;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Value;

@UtilityClass
@Slf4j
public class ScriptExecutor {
    private String getScriptType(final String scriptPath) {
        int lastDotIndex = scriptPath.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (lastDotIndex != -1) {
            String extension = scriptPath.substring(lastDotIndex + 1);
            if ("py".equals(extension)) {
                return "python";
            } else if ("js".equals(extension)) {
                return "js";
            }
        }
        return "java";
    }

    public static Object executeScript(final String script, final String functionName, final Object... args) {
        ;
        try (Context context = Context.newBuilder().allowAllAccess(true).build()) {
            context.eval(getScriptType((String) args[0]), script);
            Value function = context.getBindings(getScriptType((String) args[0])).getMember(functionName);
            if (function.canExecute()) {
                return function.execute(args).as(Object.class);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Function " + functionName + " is not executable please check your script");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("There was an error executing the message modifier script");
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Problem:
Since jPOS operates outside the HTTP request context, using RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() to access request-specific data results in the following error:

No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes
outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of
the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within
a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably
running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use
RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
request. java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request
found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
web request, or processing a request outside of the originally
receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside
of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or
RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
at com.sanjok.iso8583.MessageModifyFilter.filter(MessageModifyFilter.java:37)
at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.applyOutgoingFilters(BaseChannel.java:963)

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Regarding Andrés Alcarraz`s query,why applying filters when creating the message isn’t ideal for my situation:
Centralized Configuration: I currently have a centralized configuration for both incoming and outgoing messages, like this:
<filter class="com.test.iso8583.MessageModifyFilter"  logger="Q2">
    <property name="request-modifier-script-Path" value="${catalina.base}/conf/iso8583/request-modifier.js"/>
    <property name="response-modifier-script-Path" value="${catalina.base}/conf/iso8583/response-modifier.js"/>
</filter>

Splitting this configuration to different parts of the application would complicate maintenance and reduce coherence.
Middleware Application: My application is a middleware that deals with multiple clients. Some clients do not echo back fields correctly (e.g., sending back 000000111111 instead of 111111). I need to modify the response before qmux makes equality comparison for the provided key field.

Why not applying the filters when creating the message? The filter at channel level will be executed async, so there will never be a request context associated, the channel adaptor doesn't know which instance called it. Unless you are not using channel adaptor, and the channel directly. To help you better we need to know how you are sending the message from the spring side

@AndrésAlcarraz I have update the post trying to provide more clarity.

You may want to take a look at the BSHFilter for inspiration
(https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/bsh/BSHFilter.java).

There is no way, other than put those headers in some space, in a queue that can be derived from some unique key in the ISOMsg, you could achive that by creating a UUID, and then put that UUID in the ISOMsg. In the filter method you can remove that field. I believe thatif you choose a field over whats available in the packager it will be automatically ignored, but not sure. For provideing a detailed answer I would need the code on how you are sending the mesage from the spring side which yyou still didn´t share

My ISOMsg will have a unique field  ie. field 11. What if is use  NameRegistrar.register(msg.get(11), dataHolderObjectForThisUniqueId);
and latter unregister it .
